# WebBrowser.Navigate

Tags: c#, webbrowser

Возникает такая проблема - подключаю пространство имен System.Windows.Forms, пробую использовать WebBrowser.Navigate - Компилятор выдает ошибку, о том что WebBrowser не содержит определение для Navigate. Что делать?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace main
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            WebBrowser.Naviagate("https://vk.com/feed");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну... вы же вызываете его как статический метод. Естетственно, происходит ошибка, потому что у класса WebBrowser нет такого статического метода. Вам надо поместить на форму экземпляр объекта WebBrowser и вызывать метод у него.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Program
{
    private static WebBrowser _browser;

    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        _browser = new WebBrowser();
        _browser.Navigate("Куда желаете?");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать, например, если требуется обработать OnClick событие:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

Process.Start("https://vk.com/feed");
```